# How can I fit different sized flex items in one line?

Tags: html, css

So I have a flex container with 6 flex items and images inside of them. I need to display them as shown in the picture below:
[image]

So I want to have flex items of different sizes in two lines, and to fit images to fill a div.
But my layout looks like this:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="pic_container">
        <div class="pic_block">
            <img src="img/pic_1.jpg" id="block1">
        </div>
        <div class="pic_block">
            <img src="img/pic_2.jpg" id="block2">
        </div>
        <div class="pic_block" id="block3">
            <img src="img/pic_3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="pic_block" id="block4">
            <img src="img/pic_4.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="pic_block" id="block5">
            <img src="img/pic_5.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="pic_block" id="block6">
            <img src="img/pic_6.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.pic_container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width:100%;
    height:1100px;
    background-color: black;
}

.pic_block{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

#block1, #block2, #block5, #block6{
    width:30%;
}

#block3, #block4{
    width:39%;
}


.pic_block img{
    object-fit: contain;
    width:500px;
}
```

So I tried to do as in the example, making div widths as 30% and 39%, so two divs with 30% and one div with 39% would fill the whole screen, but instead, third div just goes to the next line.

Comment: Would be easier to find a solution for you if you can create an fiddle of your current code you've written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you are giving a width (`30%` and `39%`) to your image containers, just to overwrite it with `width: 500px;` to your img tags themselves, change that to `100%`.

Second, your `block1` and `block2` tags are put on the `img` tag instead of `div` so the whole thing breaks. thats why your 2 first images look so different.

Last, remove `flex: 1 1 auto;` from your `.pic_block` class.

Comment: hi! thanks, the divs are actually proper size now, but how could i make my images fill the whole div? for now it only works with full width, but they're not fully filling a div in height

Comment: First you need to somehow give a height to your images, that could be `height: 100%` for img tags and `height: 50%` for your containers. then adding `object-fit: cover` should solve your problem, even tho this might result in the edges of your image being hidden if their ratio doesnt match, so you need to use `object-fit: contain` for sensitive data.